# RxJava list of request

Tags: android, request, rx-java

Sorry for my english. I have list of id category, and i did request like this:

```
for(Product cat:all_cats) {
            new DefaultMediator()
                    .getProductsInCatalog(cat.getID())
                    .timeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(list_products -> {
                                //do something
                            },
                            throwable -> {
                                Log.e("asd", "asd");
                            });
        }
```

i think it not good. How i can send list of request use rxJava ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can achieve this by combining two operators:

[fromIterable or fromArray](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/from.html) : to create observable from all_cats

[concatMap](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html) : for network call and preserve the order

the code will look like this:

```
Observable.fromIterable(all_cats)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .concatMap(cat ->
                    new DefaultMediator()
                            .getProductsInCatalog(cat.getID())
                            .timeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            )
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(list_products -> {
                        //do something
                    },
                    throwable -> {
                        Log.e("asd", "asd");
                    });
```